# Accidentally deleted ICEauthority and Xauthority files

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.10

I've accidentally deleted `ICEauthority`, `Xauthority` files, and some more files (but don't know what files).

Actually I ran the command below to delete empty files on the root directory with sudo privilege, though I terminated the process in between, and now I cant log in. How to login again and to restore the necessary files? I can login into terminal but not into desktop.

The command I ran:

```
sudo find / -size 0 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~/.ICEauthority` and `~/.Xauthority` are updated automatically whenever you log in to a graphical environment. Losing those only breaks things until a reboot, at worst. (Besides, if they were empty, then they weren't being used in the first place.)

The same applies also to everything you deleted from `/dev` and `/run`, the contents of which are regenerated dynamically. (Items in `/dev`, however, are *device nodes* which always appear as 0 bytes sized, as they act as interfaces to kernel drivers instead of holding data. Similarly, `/run` often holds local sockets.) When you reboot, those directories should be filled again.

I'd be more concerned with *other* zero-length files that you deleted this way. Frankly, it is a **very stupid idea** to just delete all system files matching some arbitrary criteria.

Comment: While a reboot *will* fix the problem, it would also be nice to know how to fix the problem without resulting to a reboot.

Comment: This [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659367/148900) helped me get the right data back into .Xauthority and allowed me to start creating new clients/windows again.